# How to use bibtex for references instead of bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing my thesis using overleaf. Our department has a thesis template to use. However, The reference file is a separate file and it used \bibitem as you see in the screenshot. In \bibitem, I need to enter the reference manually.  I would like to use BibTeX because it's easy to use since I have to extract the reference from Google Scholar and add it to the template. Is there any way to use BibTeX in the same template instead of bibitem?

Thank you in advance

[image: Thesis Templete]

Comment: bibtex writes a tex file with a `thebibliography` environment containing `\bibitem` so it fits what you show perfectly, just get bibtex to write that not by hand, but it is the same latex commands in either case.

Comment: So, for example the refrence for this paper using bibtex is @article{otani2021flexible,
  title={Flexible Scan Statistics for Detecting Spatial Disease Clusters: The rflexscan R Package},
  author={Otani, Takahiro and Takahashi, Kunihiko},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Software},
  volume={99},
  pages={1--29},
  year={2021}
}, Do you mean I use the whole code under \bibitem? If I did so, the output for the reference is look weird.

Comment: no just use a .bib file as usual and replace `\input{Biblio-LQE}` in the main file by `\bibliography{yourbibfile}`  all `\bibliography` does is input a file of bibitem as you show, but gets the bibtex program to make that file.